# How to populate string-array items with different names without changing the same value?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm new to android development. *in my project* I have **a spinner, string array and a JSON adapter**,all I want is my *string array must show different array item names but still have same value.*

**Note** JSON data is online.

```
    public class CurrencyFragment extends Fragment
{
    Spinner text_meter, spinner2;
    Button button_meter;
    EditText mEdit;
    TextView result1, result2, result3, result4, result5,result6,result7, result8, result9, result10, result11, result12;


    MyRestClient myRestClient;

    public CurrencyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currency, container, false);
        text_meter = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        button_meter = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mEdit = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.Text_value);
        final SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("asd", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



        spinner2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.Currency, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

        myRestClient.getClient().getCurrencies(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void success(JsonObject jsonObject, Response response) {
                JsonPrimitive timeStampDate = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("timestamp");
                final JsonObject quotes = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("quotes");
                //final JsonObject date = jsonObject.date("timestamp");
                final JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
                final JsonObject conversionObject = (JsonObject) jp.parse(String.valueOf(quotes));

                //saving data
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = pref.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(quotes);
                prefsEditor.putString("quotes", json);
                prefsEditor.commit();


                //Getting data
                Gson gson1 = new Gson();
                String json1 = pref.getString("quotes", null);
                JsonObject inMemoryRates = (JsonObject) jp.parse(String.valueOf(json1));

                inMemoryRates.get("USD2EUR");

               // quotes obj = gson.fromJson(json, quotes.class);
                Log.d("LOL",json1);

                final Float usd2inr1 = Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDEUR").toString());
                final Float usd2inr = Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDINR").toString());
                //Float datetime = Float.valueOf(timeStampDate.get(("timeStampDate")).toString());
                final Float usd2eur = Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDEUR").toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "USD to EURO rate is " + usd2inr1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                button_meter.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                Float divisor = Float.valueOf(conversionObject.get(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString()).getAsString());

                                Float val = Float.valueOf(mEdit.getText().toString()) / divisor;

                                if (spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString() == "USDINR") {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "USD to EURO rate is " + usd2eur, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                result1.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDEUR").toString())));
                                result2.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDGBP").toString())));
                                result3.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDCAD").toString())));
                                result4.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDPLN").toString())));
                                result5.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDUSD").toString())));
                                result6.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDINR").toString())));
                                result7.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDMXN").toString())));
                                result8.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDAUD").toString())));
                                result9.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDBGN").toString())));
                                result10.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDCZK").toString())));
                                result11.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDCNY").toString())));
                                result12.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(quotes.get("USDDKK").toString())));

                            }
                        });

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could not fetch Live currencies ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                final JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
                Gson gson1 = new Gson();
                final String json1 = pref.getString("quotes", null);
                final JsonObject inMemoryRates = (JsonObject) jp.parse(String.valueOf(json1));

                final Float usd2inr1 = Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDINR").toString());
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "USD to EURO rate is " + usd2inr1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                button_meter.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                Float divisor = Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString()).getAsString());

                                Float val = Float.valueOf(mEdit.getText().toString()) / divisor;


                                result1.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDINR").toString())));
                                result2.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDGBP").toString())));
                                result3.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDCAD").toString())));
                                result4.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDPLN").toString())));
                                result5.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDUSD").toString())));
                                result6.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDINR").toString())));
                                result7.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDMXN").toString())));
                                result8.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDAUD").toString())));
                                result9.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDBGN").toString())));
                                result10.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDCZK").toString())));
                                result11.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDCNY").toString())));
                                result12.setText(String.valueOf(val * Float.valueOf(inMemoryRates.get("USDDKK").toString())));

                            }
                        });



            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

My string array item

```
<string-array name="Currency">
    <item>USDEUR</item>
    <item>USDGBP</item>
    <item>USDCAD</item>
    <item>USDPLN</item>
    <item>USDUSD</item>
    <item>USDINR</item>
    <item>USDMXN</item>
    <item>USDAUD</item>
    <item>USDBGN</item>
    <item>USDCZK</item>
    <item>USDCNY</item>
    <item>USDDKK</item>
</string-array>
```

This is REST client class
public class MyRestClient {

```
   private static RestInterface restInterface;

    public static RestInterface getClient(){
        if( restInterface == null ) {
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint("http://apilayer.net/api")
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .build();
            restInterface = restAdapter.create(RestInterface.class);
        }
        return restInterface;
    }

    public interface RestInterface {

        @GET("/live?access_key=7c1ae65f4e0d77ead7b169bb4bd0f90&currencies=EUR,GBP,CAD,PLN,USD,INR,MXN,JPN,AUD,BGN,CZK,CNY,DKK&source=USD&format=1")
        void getCurrencies(Callback<JsonObject> callback);

    }
}
```

*I want my spinner to show some thing like this
US Dollar,*
Indian Rupee
an so with different names instead of USDEUR,USDCAD,USDGBP...etc

Comment: have another parallel array with those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work around it by defining an another array in your resources, that has the corresponding "common sense" names to your Currency array with the *same indexes*. Like this

```
<string-array name="CurrencyMappings">
<item>US Dollar to Euro</item>
...
<item>US Dollar to DKK</item>
</string-array>
```

Then change your code that deals with UI to display this array in the spinner, basically replace `Currency` with `CurrencyMappings`.

Now to get the conversion codes from the user selection you need to change

```
Float divisor = Float.valueOf(conversionObject.get(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString()).getAsString());
```

so that instead of getting selected item from spinner2, you get  the index of the selected item from spinner 2 that now has the common sense values, and use this index to get the conversion code from `Currency` array. This value then becomes the divisor.

Additionally, if you are using XMl layouts, you can add

```
android:entries="@array/CurrencyMappings"
```

to your spinner layout, so you dont have to populate it in code.